# Docker from image python:3.6 apk-get not fount

Tags: python, docker, apk

In my docker roject i need the python:3.6 image (i don't need the alpinr version).
my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apk-get add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk-get update && apk-get add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
...
```

but when i build my image i get:

> Step 3/12 : RUN apk-get add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
>    ---> Running in 13913a86fd5e
>   /bin/sh: 1: apk-get: not found

i also try with apk instead apk-get but the result don't change

Someone can ask me how to install packages on this python distribution?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it apt-get? (notice the T in apt)

Comment: Replace apk-get to apt-get or only apt

Comment: If image is based on Ubuntu - use apt/apt-get, if Alpine - use apk. Package managers are different there and of course have different command arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`apk` is the package manager on alpine. The debian package manager is named [ap**t**-get](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-get).

When using apt-get in a docker file, the first call should be `apt-get update`, as the docker images do not have any package libraries cached locally.

The package names are also not identical between debian and alpine. In summary, your code should look something like

```
FROM python:3.6-buster
RUN apt-get update \
    apt-get install -y \
        make linux-headers-amd64 libffi-dev libjpeg-dev libz-dev \
        postgresql-server-dev-11 gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.6
```

then let us say build command is `docker build -t python3.6 .`. If you login to bash shell using `docker run --rm -it python3.6 /bin/bash` and run `cat /etc/issue` you will find that it is running Debian 10. Thus, you should be using `apt-get` or `apt`.